# Emacs ESS indent after %>%

Tags: r, emacs, indentation, ess

For R code my current emacs ESS style is C++ which results in

```
worst <- flights_sml %>%
    group_by(year, month, day)
```

I.e. the continuation is indented 4 spaces after `%>%`. I'd like it to be 2 spaces.

How can I do that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's not entirely clear what you want. If only want 2 spaces in continued statements such as those after a pipe, the following should work

```
(setq ess-offset-continued '(straight 2))
```

So, indentation would still be default of 4 spaces as set in the C++ style, eg. results would look like

```
worst <- flights_sml %>%
  group_by(year, month, day)

f <- function(x) {
    x
}
```

Otherwise, if you always want 2 space offsets

```
(setq ess-indent-offset 2)
```

You can customize these variables in your mode hook, eg.

```
(defun my-R-hook ()
  (setq-local ess-style 'C++)
  (setq-local ess-offset-continued '(straight 2)))
```

See the documentation for `ess-offset-continued` and `ess-style-alist` for further details.

Comment: I decided to try global 2-space offsets. Thanks, also, for pointing out `ess-style-alist` as it answers all my questions concerning indenting.